# PHP Gmagick extension

Tags: php, javascript, gmagick

Is there a way to get all the colors of an image?

Example this image
[image]

The output should have the colors:
yellow,black,blue.
It can also result in a Hex Value.

Can someone tell me any idea how to get that result? or maybe someone has already implemented this one, kindly show it to me.

Thanks. Any help would be greatly rewarded and appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to place the image in a `<canvas>`, and run through all the pixels...

Answer (score 0):

What about this thread: [most colors used (color analysis)](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12818)